# Custom function to replace lambdas Contains, StartsWith and EndsWith

Tags: c#, optimization, lambda

Is it possible to create a custom lambda function that I can replace with the `.Contains()/.StartsWith()/EndsWith()` calls below?

If so, I don't have to compare the `search` string here, but I can do it in this custom function. This would remove 2/3 of the code below, if I'm right.

...or if you have any other ideas on how to minimize this I'd be glad to hear it!

```
private void searcher(ref Expression<Func<Party, bool>> predicate, string search, string keyword, string column)
{
    if (search == "contain")
    {
        if (column == "surname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.surname.Contains(keyword));
        if (column == "lastname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.lastname.Contains(keyword));
        if (column == "comment") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.comment.Contains(keyword));
        if (column == "position") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.position.Contains(keyword));
    }
    else if (search == "start")
    {
        if (column == "surname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.surname.StartsWith(keyword));
        if (column == "lastname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.lastname.StartsWith(keyword));
        if (column == "comment") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.comment.StartsWith(keyword));
        if (column == "position") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.position.StartsWith(keyword));
    }
    else if (search == "end")
    {
        if (column == "surname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.surname.EndsWith(keyword));
        if (column == "lastname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.lastname.EndsWith(keyword));
        if (column == "comment") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.comment.EndsWith(keyword));
        if (column == "position") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.position.EndsWith(keyword));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also replace "search" with an second delegate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be tempted to write an extension for string (Note this would be better still with an enum for `where`):

```
public static bool Exists(this string str, string where, string what)
{
   if(where == "start") return str.StartsWith(what);
   if(where == "end") return str.EndsWith(what);
   if(where == "contain") return str.Contains(what);
   return false;
}
```

Then your code becomes a bit simpler:

```
private void searcher(ref Expression<Func<Party, bool>> predicate, string search, string keyword, string column)
{
    if (column == "surname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.surname.Exists(search ,keyword));
    if (column == "lastname") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.lastname.Exists(search ,keyword));
    if (column == "comment") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.comment.Exists(search ,keyword));
    if (column == "position") predicate = predicate.And(p => p.position.Exists(search ,keyword));
}
```

Comment: I think I like this better...probably because I understand it better =/

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `search` with a 2nd delegate like below:

```
private void searcher(ref Expression<Func<Party, bool>> predicate, Func<string, string, bool> searchPredicate, string keyword, string column)
{
        if (column == "surname") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchPredicate(p.surname, keyword));
        if (column == "lastname") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchPredicate(p.lastname, keyword));
        if (column == "comment") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchPredicate(p.comment, keyword));
        if (column == "position") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchPredicate(p.position, keyword));
}
```

Then you could be free to pass in any delegate that calls from a string to a string and returns bool:

```
searcher(yourFirstPredicate, (s, k) => s.Contains(k), column);
```

**Or** if you really want to use the word as the key for the search delegate you could define a method to return your delegate:

```
private static Func<string, string, bool> searchSwitcher(string searchType)
{
    switch(searchType)
    {
        case "end":
            return (s, k) => s.EndsWith(k);
        case "start":
            return (s, k) => s.StartsWith(k);
        default:
            return (s, k) => s.Contains(k);
    }
}
```

Then change your searcher() method to:

```
private void searcher(ref Expression<Func<Party, bool>> predicate, string search, string keyword, string column)
{
    var searchDelegate = searchSwitcher(search);

        if (column == "surname") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchDelegate(p.surname, keyword));
        if (column == "lastname") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchDelegate(p.lastname, keyword));
        if (column == "comment") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchDelegate(p.comment, keyword));
        if (column == "position") predicate = predicate.And(p => searchDelegate(p.position, keyword));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution within a generic method that uses reflection and an expression tree.  Probably overkill for that you need, but it gave me an excuse to mess around with expression tree's.

```
    private bool Searcher<T>(T obj, string search, string keyword, string column)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(column);
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "contain", "Contains" }, { "start", "StartsWith" }, { "end", "EndsWith" } };
        if (property != null && dict.ContainsKey(search) )
        {
            ParameterExpression objExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
            MemberExpression prop = Expression.Property(objExpression, property);
            MethodCallExpression startsWith = Expression.Call(prop, typeof(String).GetMethod(dict[search], new Type[] { typeof(String) }), Expression.Constant(keyword));
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(startsWith, objExpression);
            var func = expression.Compile();
            return func(obj);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```